# Incorrect Back button behavior

Tags: bug, android-app

Sequence: select site in drawer, select "tags", select one tag, select question. So I read question. Than I press Back. I'm expecting return to messages list, but I get list of tags.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: Nexus 5X

  - OS Version: 7.1.1 (3425388)